# Trying to set style as screen height and width CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I am trying to do is get the height of the screen and the width of the screen and then use the document.getElement.style.property = newStyle to change the style to the obtained height of the screen and width of the screen. I tried making the height and width into Strings to use, I also tried putting just the values in. I want to know how to put in px values and % values. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en/US">
<head>
<title>
cyclebg test

</title>
<style>
body {
background: url("http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/03/22/13/32738A6E00000578-3504412-image-a-6_1458654517341.jpg") 
no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
background-size: 200px 100px;

}

p {
padding: 50px; background-color: green; margin-left: -1%; margin-right: -1%; display: block;


}


</style>
</head>


<body>

<p style = "margin-top: 25%;"> Hello World </p>      

 <p> Yo </p>
</body>


<script>

var heightOfScreen = screen.height;
var widthOfScreen = screen.width;
var heightOfScreenString = heightOfScreen + " px";
var widthOfScreenString = widthOfScreen + " px";
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundSize = "heightOfScreenString widthOfScreenString";
</script>


</html>
```

Comment: I am trying to change the background-size in response to the user's screen size, sorry if I was vague

Answer (score 0):

You should try using

```
background-size: cover;
```

So the background will cover the whole size of the background and cropoff the excess.
If you want the full background to show (despite of blank spaces on top or sides) you can use "contain" instead

https://jsfiddle.net/0vps9x0s/

Comment: Brilliant! I had forgot about this, +1 for keeping it smart & simple, thank you & well done.

Answer (score 0):

This shortest & simplest answer is to use CSS to cover the background image and crop the excess, using this:

```
background-size: cover;
```

If you want to *"fit"* the background image to the container, use this:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

If you want use jQuery to get the width & height of the window and set the size of the background image, do this:

```
var width = $(window).width();
var height = $(window).height();
// NOTE: this does the same thing as "background-size: 100% 100%;"
$("body").css("background-size", width + "px " + height + "px");
```

If you just want to use Vanilla JavaScript to get the width & height of the window and set the size of the background image, use this:

```
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;
// NOTE: this does the same thing as "background-size: 100% 100%;"
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundSize = width + "px " + height + "px";
```

Good luck and all the best.